# Issue with NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table -> 35 records

SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  x IN (SELECT x 
             FROM   table1)  -> 34 records

SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  x NOT IN (SELECT x 
                 FROM   table1) -> 0 records
```

Any ideas as to how this could be possible?

Comment: did you check for null values

Comment: One of your records has `NULL` value in **x**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix for the `NULL` value is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  x NOT IN (SELECT x 
                 FROM   table1
                 WHERE x is not null);
```

However, it is recommended to use `not exists` rather than `not in` because of the `NULL` issue:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.x = t.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your `x` values is `NULL`. `NULL` values will never evaluate to `true` in any comparison (since the value is unknown).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, 1 of your values is likely to be NULL. You can test for this using IS NULL in your WHERE clause. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn IS NULL
```

This simple example would find all records in MyTable that have NULL in MyColumn.

Answer (score 0):

"Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.
"

[NOT/IN MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

for a Note, NOT IN is appropriate when you know the number of rows coming from sub-query will remain always small and finite values.
it is not advisable if that list items are uncertain. instead use the LEFT JOIN type query.

EDIT-1 For @John Gibb

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
        id  INT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @t1 TABLE
    (
        id  INT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @t (id) SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT 2
    INSERT INTO @t1 (id) SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL

    SELECT *
    FROM @t
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @t1)

    SELECT *
    FROM @t t
    LEFT JOIN @t1 t1
    ON t.id=t1.id
    WHERE t1.id IS NULL
    AND t.id IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Comment: I don't agree with using left joins over not ins. They aren't logically equivalent, left join will give you extra rows if the join values aren't unique. I'd recommend not exists instead...

Comment: i didn't say the LeftJoin is same as NotIN. I mentioned that in context of two things. you can implement NOTIN using right format of LEFT-JOIN. When "NOT IN Items" are from sub-query many times the result may go large enough to fail the query with error mentioned in the MSDN. in the context of OP, many other simpler solutions are also possible if this scenario is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd still go with `where not exists` - it's more clearly expressing your intent and therefore more readable, and will likely be more efficiently implemented as a `left anti semi join` instead of a `left outer join`

Comment: yes that's individual's choice depending on the requirement. remember that "WHERE NOT EXIST" will perform slow if the tables involve are large enough or they become large over time. it can not utilize your indexes properly. Developer writing query might not have even think about that and does not consider the indexes on table. where as IF the query is written with LEFT JOIN then most likely developer will not have to worry about this thing over time if suddenly the table receives large data and query is performing slow.

Comment: It will not "perform slow if the tables are large enough", where did you get that idea? It will use indexes just fine, and will still likely perform better than left join with large tables.

Comment: I just read that MSDN link, and think I better understand the confusion.. it appears that they're referring to using `not in` like `not in (1,2,3,4)`... if you have too many items listed there, it'll run out of resources. That doesn't apply to using `not in` with a subquery; in fact, they recommend putting your values in a table and using a subquery to work around that limitation.